# Anderson Gill counting process for recurrent events: covariates?

Tags: r, censoring

I have a dataset I made using Anderson-Gill counting process template. i.e each person appears in $N+1$ rows where $N$ is the number of events they had. $N$ rows for the $N$ events and 1 row for the censor time from last event time. Entrance and exit times are measured in days. Event=1 indicates the event occurred.

[image: the data set up]

My question is about covariates. Let's say I have smoking and age. Are they all supposed to be from the "at risk" time point, i.e in this case, the baseline of the person. OR are they supposed to change with time based on the interval? I am confused about this kindly help ...

Answer (score 0):

Survival models typically assume that the risk of an event at any time is related to the covariate values that are in place at that time: not only at the times of events that an individual experiences, but also at the times of events in which an individual is in the risk set for comparison against the individual who had an event. In that scenario, the covariate values should be changing with time.

The way this plays out in practice, however, depends on the nature of each covariate and your idea about how each covariate is associated with outcome.

For example, if you model age as linearly related to log-hazard in a Cox model, there is no need to recalculate the age values at all event times, as the [R time dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) explains in Section 5. If you model it non-linearly (often a good choice), however, then you need to include changing age values in your data set, as that vignette Section shows.

For a covariate like smoking, the current yes/no smoking status might not be the best choice. Event risk is typically better explained by longer-term measures of smoking history, like cigarette pack-years. If you are using pack-years, then you probably should provide current values for each time.

Other types of measures of smoking history might be considered; for example, was there any history of smoking in the past 15 years? That type of measure might also need to be updated over time in your data set, or maybe best expressed (if possible) as a continuous variable of time since the last tobacco use.

Sometimes smoking history is evaluated instead as ever/never. Unless someone takes up smoking for the first time at an advanced age, that covariate value won't change over time in most applications. It would be a potentially time-varying covariate whose value is constant for most or all individuals.

Thus you need to consider the details of each covariate for making these decisions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear enough to just say you are just adjusting for "age" and "smoking status". Aside from the nuances with which how these variables are measured, the study design is longitudinal and these are potentially time varying covariates.

It is not necessarily true that you *must* model the cross-sectional association between the covariates and the response - in that case, age has to be captured as a birthdate which may not be possible due to HIPAA, and smoking status will *always* be interval censored, since if I am a never smoker today and have "event" tomorrow, I just might have taken up smoking in-between and you never knew. It seems unreasonable to think this might happen, but it underscores the need to outline assumptions clearly and discuss limitations.

One obvious choice for adjustment is the covariate value at time 0 - meaning the time of entry into the study. Many longitudinal studies collect baseline covariate data only. Consider that if age is modeled as a time varying covariate, then what is the appropriate interpretation of the baseline hazard function?

The choice of adjustment for time-varying confounders typically has to deal with a complex, time-relational causal modeling such as the issue of confounding by indication, example here: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1536867X0400400403
Obviously there isn't enough detail in your post about "event" to say if this is the case.

Comment: These are great answers and i am assuming that you are thinking about cox regression or some regression models while talking about time varying covariates- i wanted to understand specifically for kalplan meier curves however (from the anderson gill Data)- even for reccurent events for each person, the data time point should be baseline right?